# Admob interstitial house ads

Tags: ios, admob, interstitial

I have implement admob trying to get interstitial house ads working.

```
interstitial_ = [[GADInterstitial alloc] init];
interstitial_.adUnitID = @"xxxMediationInterstitialID";
GADRequest *request = [GADRequest request];
request.testing = YES;    
[interstitial_ loadRequest:request];
```

When I set the testing flag to yes, things load fine.  I know you need to be invited for paid ads, but I’d like to create a house ad for the in app purchase to remove the ads ideally.

I am confused on the create interstitial house ad section on the admob website.  It seems like they allow you to upload a custom banner for the ad, but I don’t see how to do it.  Just “third party url”.  Is there a way to get the house ads to show in my testing?  Where do I upload a banner?  I’m sure its something simple, I just couldn’t find exactly where/how to do it.  Has anyone done this?  Should I set the test flag to NO?  (it always says no content or something...)

Comment: Upload your banner on your own server and then use that URL. I think that should work. Try imgur or any other photo sharing site if you don't have your own server.

Comment: Oh ok... the way they have it worded seems like you’d load it there.   Thanks.

Comment: Then how do you tell it to go to the in app purchase or call a method when the user clicks the ad?

Comment: You'd have to look into the admob API for that, sorry. Something like that would be a method in the API if it exists.

Comment: Yes the only one I thought it might be is..  - (void)interstitialWillPresentScreen:(GADInterstitial *)interstitial but it doesn’t seem to do that.  It just loads the webpage.

Comment: Immediately dismiss the screen that comes up and then use "- (void)interstitialWillDismissScreen:(GADInterstitial *)ad;" to your advantage.

Comment: Well we you don’t want it to go there if the user tries to cancel?  Only if they voluntarily click on the ad?

Comment: A user tries to cancel? Can't you put a button for "go back" on your in app purchase? This is all super complicated actually... you should just use a custom UIButton with an image set on it for your banner lol. Any particular reason to use admob? It just adds overhead.

Comment: Yea, that’s a good point... I guess I could just do a method myself.  Sounds like a plan.

Comment: Just FYI, an interstitial is used for impressions.  There is no concept of a click for an interstitial.  You would want a banner ad for this.  However, I'm not sure how you would set the click url of an AdMob house ad to go to a specific view controller to showcase the in-app purchase option, so Tanvir's suggestion is probably easiest.

Comment: Another FYI: In iOS (On some versions of the admob sdk) there is a limit to the amount of interstitial adverts that are displayed for each user (by UDID) per day. If you are getting an error "No ad to show" you may have already recevied too many interstitial ads for that day.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set request.testing = NO, the testing is only intended for debugging and making sure your implementation works - and to make sure you don't violate Google rule by showing and clicking your own ads while developing. Once you're ready to release you app, make sure to set testing to no!

If you implement the delegate function didFailToReceiveAdWithError you can do a NSLog of the error and see why you don't receive any ads - maybe there aren't any available in your region?

For house ads you'll have to upload it to the admob page, and they will make sure to serve it to your app when it requests ads. I don't have any hands on experience with this (yet) so I can't bring you any further.

But actually I'm trying to do the exact same thing in my app - offer in-app purchase in the case there is no interstitial ads to be served. I'm thinking (but not sure) that a house ad will not translate into an in-app function call that implement the in-app purchase. I'm thinking I'll attempt to display AdMobs interstitial and if that fails I'll slide my own view with my in-app purchase offer on it and a button on top of the current view. I have yet to implement the details ;-)

Comment: Kristian, could you implement it as you described it? I'm struggling with Interstitial House Ads myself.

Comment: thomers, yes I have it working as I described. To see what it looks like: [Is it Friday](http://app2.it/friday). My impression is that very few interstitial ads are available so I think I'm presenting my own view controller most of the time. It simply has a picture on it, a label that can be localized and a button that will activate in-app purchase code already implemented elsewhere in the app. I'm happy to share the code with you, but I don't think this is the proper issue for that. If you have an issue for your question, please let me know and I'll drop the code there.